# Magento 2.3 mail error (vendor/zendframework/zend-mime/src/Message.php)

Tags: email, magento, zend-framework, magento-2.3

Since `Magento 2.3` I'm unable to send order emails.

I got the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getHeaders() on null in /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mime/src/Message.php:167
```

I don't know anything about `Zend` and the line at 167 also doesn't make any sense. All I know is that everything worked at `Magento 2.2.x`. Since 2.3 they released a new version of Zend Framework. This zend-mime folder is new.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found out the cause of this issue. I used a PDF invoice module which should have been compatible with Magento 2.3 but it's not. After deleting the module and upgrade/clean etc. everything worked as expected.